# Prove or disprove: $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ is an eigenvalue of A $\implies\overline\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm pretty sure it's true because every time I calculated eigenvalues for a complex matrix it eventually boiled down to solving a quadratic formula that gave me a conjugated pair, but not sure how to prove it.

Comment: $$A = \begin{bmatrix}i & 0\\ 0 & i\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: If you're talking about real matrices, you're right, of course. Complex roots of real polynomials occur in conjugate pairs.

Comment: What is always true is that the eigenvalues of the adjoint of $\;A\;$ , i.e. the matrix $\;A^*:=\overline{A^t}\;$, are $\;\overline\lambda$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo or even of $\overline A$

Comment: Give an example calculation that you made and together we look what's happening